# Removing code duplication in detecting EOR vs EOF

Tags: perl, loops, parsing, multiline

I am looping through multi-line records and loading them into an array.  I happen to be using Perl , but language is irrelevant as I am looking for an optimization to the algorithm.  Specifically, I am bothered by the fact that I am writing the array push twice. Once in the loop when I find an end of record (eor) and again when I run out of file (eof, not eor).  I know this doesn't affect the speed, I just don't like have to repeat the code in two places.  It means that if it changes, I have to modify in two places.

The approach I am taking is this:

```
my $data = []; #data object array
my $record = {};
my $line;
while (my $line = <$file>){
    if($line =~ /marker-a:(.*)/){
        # Update data object
        $$record{'a'} = $1;
    }
    if($line =~ /marker-b:(.*)/){
        # Update data object
        $$record{'b'} = $1;
    }
    if($line =~ /eor/){
        # End of record; add to data array
        push(@$data,$record);
        $record = {};
    }
}
#Update leftover data to data array
push(@$data,$record);
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I know I could just create a function, but I am looking for something more elegant.  I haven't tested this code, but it should give enough of an idea of what I am doing.  Let me know if any questions.

Comment: I'm basically trying to stay away from a copy and paste approach.  If there is a change in the EOR process, I also have to change the EOF process.  I'm just asking because it seems like something that must have come up time and again and I'm wondering how others handle this.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is necessary is to change

```
if ( $line =~ /eor/ )
```

to

```
if ( $line =~ /eor/ or eof )
```

and remove the `push` outside the loop

---

#### Update

Here's a more complete solution that uses best practices and avoids pushing empty records onto the array

```
my ($data, $record);

while ( <$file> ) {

    if ( /marker-([ab]):(.*)/ ) {
        $record->{$1} = $2;
    }

    if ( ( /eor/ or eof ) and $record ) {
        push @$data, $record;
        $record = undef;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will never reach the `if ( ( ... or eof )` because the loop will end before that.  i.e. as soon as it hits eof, the loop breaks out and the block is no longer processed.  That is the problem.  Then there is data cached in $record that is not pushed to $data.  Thank you, though.

Comment: @rfportilla, That's not true. `eof` returns true if the *next* read will return EOF.

Comment: @rfportilla: I'm sorry, I overlooked your comment until ikegami's response drew my attention. The code is fine. `eof` will return *true* any time after the last line is read from the file, that is, during the last iteration of the loop. It actually does a `getc` followed by an `ungetc` to check whether there is any more data in the stream without consuming it

Answer (score 3):

So you want EOR and EOF to be handled at the same place. That means that checking for EOF can't be done at the top of the loop anymore. The trick to moving the condition into the loop is to switch to an infinite loop.

```
my $data = [];
my $record = {};
while (1) {
    my $line = <$file>;
    if (!defined($line) || $line =~ /eor/) {
        push(@$data, $record) if keys(%$record);
        last if !defined($line);
        $record = {};
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /marker-a:(.*)/) {
        $record->{a} = $1;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /marker-b:(.*)/) {
        $record->{b} = $1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this approach; I just don't like using infinite loops. :-( This seems like the way to go.  Thanks for the help!